# Element not interactable - Selenium Error

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

```html
<div id="product-tabs-container">
   <div>
      <div class="ux-conveyor-clip">
         <a class="left ux-conveyor-control" data-slide="prev" role="button" href="javascript:void(0);" aria-label="previous" style="display: none;"><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
         <div class="ux-conveyor">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="margin-left: 0px;">
               <li id="description" class="nav-item " role="presentation"><button class="nav-link" role="tab" aria-selected="false">Description </button></li>
               <li id="options" class="nav-item " role="presentation"><button class="nav-link" role="tab" aria-selected="false">Inventory &amp; Options</button></li>
               <li id="shipping" class="nav-item " role="presentation"><button class="nav-link active" role="tab" aria-selected="true">Shipping</button></li>
               <li id="files" class="nav-item " role="presentation" style="display: none;"><button class="nav-link" role="tab" aria-selected="false">Downloadable Content</button></li>
               <li id="search-engines" class="nav-item " role="presentation"><button class="nav-link" role="tab" aria-selected="false">Search Engines</button></li>
               <li id="marketplaces-tab" class="nav-item " role="presentation" style="display: none;"><button class="nav-link" role="tab" aria-selected="false">Marketplaces</button></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <a class="right ux-conveyor-control" data-slide="next" role="button" href="javascript:void(0);" aria-label="next" style="display: none;"><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
      </div>
      <div aria-labelledby="shipping" role="tabpanel">
         <div>
            <h5 style="display: inline;">Weight/dimensions of the shipping package</h5>
            <span><span> <span role="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="uxicon uxicon-help" style="cursor: pointer; outline: none;"></span></span></span>
         </div>
         <p>Required for dimension-based shipping methods.</p>
         <div class="additional-options well">
            <div class="shipping-input-container">
               <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <label for="product_weight">Weight   </label>
                  <div class="input-group"><input id="product_weight" type="text" pattern="[\d,]*(\.[\d,]+)?" class="form-control ignore-invalid" value="0.00"><span class="input-group-addon">Lbs.</span></div>
               </fieldset>
            </div>
            <h5 style="margin: 20px 0px;">Dimensions</h5>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                  <div class="shipping-input-container">
                     <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <label for="product_depth">Length   </label>
                        <div class="input-group"><input id="product_depth" type="text" pattern="[\d,]*(\.[\d,]+)?" class="form-control ignore-invalid" value="0.00"><span class="input-group-addon">in.</span></div>
                     </fieldset>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                  <div class="shipping-input-container">
                     <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <label for="product_width">Width   </label>
                        <div class="input-group"><input id="product_width" type="text" pattern="[\d,]*(\.[\d,]+)?" class="form-control ignore-invalid" value="0.00"><span class="input-group-addon">in.</span></div>
                     </fieldset>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                  <div class="shipping-input-container">
                     <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <label for="product_height">Height   </label>
                        <div class="input-group"><input id="product_height" type="text" pattern="[\d,]*(\.[\d,]+)?" class="form-control ignore-invalid" value="0.00"><span class="input-group-addon">in.</span></div>
                     </fieldset>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <h5>How do you want to determine shipping cost?</h5>
         <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check"><label for="product_shipping_configuration_use_shipping_method" class="form-check-label custom-control custom-radio" id="label-product_shipping_configuration_use_shipping_method"><input id="product_shipping_configuration_use_shipping_method" type="radio" name="shipping_config" aria-labelledby="label-product_shipping_configuration_use_shipping_method" aria-required="false" class="custom-control-input" value="use_shipping_method" checked=""><span class="custom-control-indicator"></span><span class="custom-control-description"><span>Calculate for me using my <a href="/admin/shipping_methods" data-ga="" class="shipping-methods">shipping methods</a></span></span></label></div>
         </fieldset>
         <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check"><label for="product_shipping_configuration_free" class="form-check-label custom-control custom-radio" id="label-product_shipping_configuration_free"><input id="product_shipping_configuration_free" type="radio" name="shipping_config" aria-labelledby="label-product_shipping_configuration_free" aria-required="false" class="custom-control-input" value="free"><span class="custom-control-indicator"></span><span class="custom-control-description"><span>This item always ships <strong>free</strong></span></span></label></div>
         </fieldset>
         <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check"><label for="product_shipping_configuration_per_item" class="form-check-label custom-control custom-radio" id="label-product_shipping_configuration_per_item"><input id="product_shipping_configuration_per_item" type="radio" name="shipping_config" aria-labelledby="label-product_shipping_configuration_per_item" aria-required="false" class="custom-control-input" value="per_item"><span class="custom-control-indicator"></span><span class="custom-control-description">Specify a shipping fee for this item</span></label></div>
         </fieldset>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I saw a q for this but none of the answers work for me so I'm still supposed to open a new question, right?

I have this code to loop through a list of links for my bot to open and edit the products. In this example, any product in the 'brownie' category.

When it gets to 'FindElementById("product_weight")' I get attached 'Element not interactable' error.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. HTML also attached.

[image: selenium error-element not interactable]
[image: selenium error-element not interactable-HTML]

```
Dim bot As New WebDriver
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wat As Worksheet
Dim urlBase As String
Dim x As Variant

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wat = wb.Sheets("automate WAT")    
urlBase = "https://329902a6-3ae5-4c13-b329-df1f92b14ba8.onlinestore.godaddy.com/admin/products/"

with wat 'spreadsheet with links

        For Each x In Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

            If InStr(x.Offset(0, 2).Value, "brownie") > 0 Then
                bot.Get urlBase & x.Value & "/edit"
                Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 5, Now))

                'bot.FindElementById("Shipping").Click
                Set navLinkList = bot.FindElementsByCss("button")

                For Each item In navLinkList
                    If item.Text = "Shipping" Then
                    item.Click
                    Exit For
                    End If
                Next item

                Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 5, Now)) 'to make sure the fields are ready to receive data

                With bot
                    '.FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='product_weight']").SendKeys ("4.00")
                    '.FindElementByCss("#product_weight").SendKeys ("4.00")
                    .FindElementById("product_weight").SendKeys ("4.00")
                    .FindElementById("product_depth").SendKeys ("12.00")
                    .FindElementById("product_width").SendKeys ("12.00")
                    .FindElementById("product_height").SendKeys ("8.00")
                    .FindElementById("Label-product_shipping_configuration_use_shipping_method").Click
                End With 'bot

                For Each item In navLinkList
                    If item.Text = "Save" Then
                    item.Click
                    Exit For
                    End If
                Next item

                Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 5, Now))

            End If

        Next x

    End With 'wat
```

Comment: `SendKeys` is completely unreliable. You will be lucky if you can get it to work at all, and if you do, the online store will change one thing tomorrow and it will break.

Comment: Provide some explicit wait before interacting element.

Comment: @braX yeah, i'm expecting to have to update stuff regularly, sadly

Comment: @KunduK yes, i have that in there

Comment: @JoePatrick Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: hi, @DebanjanB, I have added the HTML... hopefully properly. Thanks!

Comment: @braX hi, do you have a more reliable suggestion?

Comment: @KunduK do you have any other suggestions?